# inserting vector element in queue

Tags: c++, vector, struct, queue

```
#include <iostream>
#include <queue>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    struct process
    {
        int burst;
        int ar;
    };
    int x = 4;
    int arival[x];
    int burst[x];
    ifstream arrival, burrst;
    arrival.open("arrival.txt");
    burrst.open("burrst.txt");
    for (int i = 0; i<x; i++)
    {
        arrival >> arival[i];
        burrst >> burst[i];

    }
    arrival.close();
    burrst.close();


    vector<process> a[x];

    for (int i = 0; i<x; i++)
    {
        a[i].push_back({ burst[i], arival[i] });

    }
    cout << "Process\t" << "Arrival Time\t" << "Burst Time\n";
    for (int i = 0; i<x; i++)
    {
        char k = 'A';
        cout << k << "\t" << a[i].back().burst << "\t" << a[i].back().ar << endl;
    }
    queue<process> wait, ready; /* Declare a queue */
    wait.push(a[1]);
    return 0;
}
```

The compiler is not allowing me to push vector value into queue When I try to insert `a[1]` in wait queue like this:

```
wait.push(a[1]);
```

I get the following error

> invalid arguments

Please have a look and help me to remove the error.

Comment: You have a `queue` of `process` but you're trying to push a `vector<process>` into it. Read up on how to instantiate a vector.

Comment: Not that it really matters in this example you bit `arival` and `burst` are both [VLA](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887097/variable-length-arrays-in-c) which are currently not standard.

Comment: @juanchopanza can u explain how can i complete this process?

Comment: @NathanOliver i didnt get u? can u just tell me simple step to complete this operation.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for is just a `vector` of `process`, not an array of `vector` of `process`

Instead of:

```
vector<process> a[x];
```

Use:

```
vector<process> a;
```

and then, in the for loop, use:

```
// a[i].push_back({ burst[i], arival[i] });
//  ^^^ drop this.

a.push_back({ burst[i], arival[i] });
```